# Receive value in server side( reslet java ) send from client side (php )

Tags: java, php

**Php code**

```
$name = $_REQUEST[ 'name' ];

// Create the client object.
$url = 'http://localhost:8182/hello?'.$name;
$ch = curl_init( $url );

// Set Curl options
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// Make the request
echo $response = curl_exec( $ch ); // Just getting "hello, world" and not the name.

?>
```

**my Java code.**

```
@Get
public String present( String name ){
      String name = getQuery().getValues("name");
      return "hello, world"+name;
}
```

What i am doing is, trying to send a name from client side i.e php to server side java ( restlet ).  can anyone guide me how can i achieve this task?

Comment: php is, usually, [server-side](https://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php).

Answer (score 1):

Edit this line

```
// Create the client object.
$url = 'http://localhost:8182/hello?name='.$name;
```

Comment: thanks but it seems java side is not getting the name.

Comment: can you try `System.out.println()` instead `return` ?

Comment: i tried but i think this method is wrong maybe then. `getQuery().getValues("name");`